# How to get xml file from server in OOB Application using web client method

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, out-of-browser

I am using Out of Browser Application in silverlight.

I have problem while loading xml file usine below mentioned code.

```
string contentUri = Application.Current.Host.Source
            .AbsoluteUri;
        var contentUri1 = contentUri.Substring(0, contentUri.LastIndexOf("/")) + "/Hello1.xml";

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.OpenReadCompleted+=(open,read)=>
        {


            string content;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(read.Result,Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                byte[] m_Bytes = ReadToEnd(read.Result);
                string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m_Bytes, 0, m_Bytes.Length);
            }

        };
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged
            += (chang,dh)=>
          {

            };
        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(contentUri));
```

where my xml file contained

```
<Root>
<element>FirstElement</element>
</Root>
```

I got the garbage value as output can anyone please help me how can i download that original xml content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke webclient calls on Out-Of-Browser mode it suppose that you have already RootVisual Created, because webclient will run on its Dispatcher apparently. 
If not, you end up with no response from server, and what is strange, even exception is not thrown !!

Anyway, this Post from Jeremy explains details:

http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/05/webclient-and-deploymentcatalog-gotchas.html